# Как прочитать строку из бинарного файла после закрытия программы?

Tags: c++, сериализация, io, struct, fstream

У меня есть структура

```
struct Order
{
    unsigned int productamount = 0;
    Products product = Products::OOPlabs;
    double cost = 0.0;
    string FIO = "Иванов Иван Иванович";
    unsigned int orderID = 0;
};
```

Я записываю массив из неё в бинарный файл и читаю при помощи следующих функций:

```
bool createbinfile(string way, Order* request, int reqlen)
{
    ofstream f(way, ios::trunc | ios::binary);
    if (!f.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не найден\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if (f.rdstate())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка неизвестной природы\n";
        return false;
    }
    f.write((char*)&reqlen, sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < reqlen; i++)
    {
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&request[i].productamount), sizeof(unsigned int));
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&request[i].product), sizeof(Products));
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&request[i].cost), sizeof(double));
        size_t tmp = request[i].FIO.length();
        f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tmp), sizeof(size_t));
        f.write(&request[i].FIO[0], tmp);
    }
    f.close();
    return true;
}

bool readbinfile(string way, Order* &request, int &len)
{
    ifstream f(way, ios::binary);
    if (!f.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Файл не найден\n";
        return false;
    }
    else if (f.rdstate())
    {
        cout << "Ошибка неизвестной природы\n";
        return false;
    }
    f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&len), sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&request[i].productamount), sizeof(unsigned int));
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&request[i].product), sizeof(Products));
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&request[i].cost), sizeof(double));
        size_t tmp = 0;
        f.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tmp), sizeof(size_t));
        request[i].FIO.resize(tmp);
        f.read(&request[i].FIO[0], tmp);
    }
    f.close();
    return true;
}
```

Я могу спокойно записывать и считывать в бинарный файл структуру со строкой во время исполнения программы, но после выхода из неё и повторного чтения - write access violation в void assign () _left was ... (_Right в этот момент равно нуль символу). Я в курсе, что string не POD, но так как мне её записать в бинарном виде? Что именно в этот момент записывается в бинарный файл? Вообще адрес на строку, поэтому я не могу её повторно прочитать, или весь объект строка - поэтому так происходит? Даже если так, как надо записывать в бинарном режиме такой тип данных? Наставьте на путь истинный пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для полного контроля: при считывании размера списка нужно выделить память под весь массив.

```
request = (Order*)operator new (sizeof(Order)*len);
```

Дальше вызвать конструкторы структур на каждый элемент.

```
for(size_t i=len;i>0;){--i; new (request + i) Order;}
```

или для краткости:

```
   request = new Order[len];
```

Строки там будут уже Иванами. Дальше можно пробовать так , как вы и хотели:

```
  request[i].FIO.resize(tmp);
  f.read(&request[i].FIO[0], tmp);
```

Удаление массива нужно также в обратном порядке, с полным контролем:

```
  for(size_t i=len;i>0;){
      -- i;
      (request + i)->~Order();}

  operator delete (request);
```

или для краткости:

```
delete [] request ;
```

Comment: Но тогда ловлю ту же ошибку на строке request[i].FIO.resize(tmp); даже при работе программы

Comment: Описка была, надо так: `for(size_t i=len;i>0;){--i; new (request + i) Order;}`

Comment: Вау, круто, всё правильно записывает, вы первый пионер в моей проблеме, как вы догадались так сделать, где об этом можно прочитать? Уже почти идеально работает, но теперь при каждом выходе из программы при удалении массива структур read access violation в _Container_base12::_Orphan_all ... Хотя по идее вы справились.

Comment: Ошибка при удалении возможна из-за перевыделения памяти? Если да, то как удалять новый массив?

Comment: Циклом удалять надо вручную. См. ответ.

Comment: Супер! Всё работает! Спасибо большое, нигде не мог хорошего ответа найти, даже на английском стеке спрашивал. Не подскажете, на чём основан ваш ответ?

Comment: Года, года... 999999 строчек кода и вы в теме.